# In Javascript, "for...in" doesn't iterate over properties of prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

On MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), I saw snippet like this:

```
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log('this is fog (' + name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

In the snippet, `console.log(name); // toString or something else` looks a bit confusing to me. I understand `toString` is a property of `Object.prototype` and this property can be accessed by `buz.toString`.

However,  when I run the snippet in Chrome, I didn't saw the `toString` property is printed (console.log), though the comments say it should be iterated by `for..in` and printed..

Does anyone have ideas about why the properties from one's prototype can't be iterated by "for..in"?

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString` is a non-enumerable property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for x in obj` iterates over only enumerable properties of the object (including those on the prototype).  A given property can be marked as enumerable or not.  So, if `for/in` is skipping some property, then that is likely because that property is not configured as enumerable.

See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gyc9gnmj/ that shows how only enumerable properties are iterated with `for x in obj`.

And, in fact, you can see that the `toString()` method is marked as `enumerable: false` with this code:

```js
function log(x) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
}

var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(buz), "toString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed more light in continuation with what jfriend00 has already answered, Object's data properties in JavaScript has four attributes namely [[configurable]], [[enumerable]], [[writable]] and [[value]] all of which is set to for the former three the default value is true and for the last it defaults to undefined.

Say suppose there exists a need where you would like to avoid a property's value not to be returned in a for-in loop. You can write as

```
var car = {};
Object.defineProperty(car, 'name',{
enumerable : false,
value : 'BMW'
});
```